Understanding Enforce Permission Requirements Defined on Built-In Apex Classes Used as Inputs
I am going through this release update https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_release_update_enforce_perm_requirements_on_built_in_apex_classes.htm&release=250&type=5
I do not completely understand it.
The update talks about built-in Apex class with permission requirements as input.
Which are these apex classes and what is the input ?
I do not see any examples in the documentation.
Thanks

Let's break it down to make it clearer :

Built-in Apex classes that are used as inputs for Apex actions

Apex actions are flow elements to invoke an Apex method annotated with InvocableMethod. From the following documentation :

There can be at most one input parameter and its data type must be one of the following:

A list of a user defined type, containing variables of the supported types or user-defined Apex types, with the InvocableVariable annotation.


Supported types can be built-in Apex classes, which are classes created by Salesforce and available for use in Apex like : Account, Contact, User, ... And can be used as inputs for Apex actions in a flow, as demonstrated in the previous documentation.
Now, if flow runs in user context and the current user doesn't have the required permissions on Contact which is used as Input, the flow will fail when executing the Apex action. Before this update, the Apex action might rely on the Flow's context without properly enforcing these permissions, causing unexpected failures.

Can anyone explain to me what is built-in class? Is it all standard object? Is there any documentation about this built-in class?
Thanks

@WillSmith built-in classes are classes that come out of the box with Apex, it includes classes related to standard objects and also String, Date, DateTime ... classes.

So one way of finding out whether this incomprehensible release update will affect you, is first to look for methods that are InvocableMethod? Then find out which flows use those methods and test them?

@SanderdeJong that is indeed a way of checking if the release affects your org !
